# File not writing in Server

Tags: php, file

I developed a php project. In that i'm passing the image from flash to PHP. When i'm getting the parameter value, i'm converting into the base64 format and writing into the new file.(png image). The above logic is perfectly working in my local system. But when i deployed this seeting in the server. Except the file writing everything is working.

Below is the code to generate the image.

```
$filename = $templateID.'.png';

if ($handle = fopen("images/cat_images/".$filename, 'w'))
{
    if (!fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE)
    {
        fclose($handle);

        $query = "UPDATE `products` SET `template_data`='".$signData."' WHERE `id`=$templateID LIMIT 1";
        $db->query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the images/cat_images directory?

Comment: Are you sure that your script has writing permissions in the directory you're writing to on the server? That would explain why the code works locally but not on your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to write that is definitely you do not have the write permission on that directory.

Give the write permission to directory.

EDIT

Check the path you mentioned in the `fopen` is correct. I think it is not correct according to your live directory structure.

Try to mention the full path in `fopen`

```
if ($handle = fopen("/full/path/here/images/cat_images/".$filename, 'w'))
```

Comment: The file permission for the directory was given through the Client FTP (FileZilla). If i right click and check the persmission it's showing 777. So i think the problem it's not because of file permission.

Answer (score 0):

try this `sudo chown www-data /path/to/images/ -r`

which will give ownership to apache to do the write, or add the www-data user to your group

or `sudo chmod a+w /path/to/images/ -r` to allow anyone to write there, not the best option

Comment: Is flash file can use SSL?? Because the value is passing from the falsh file to the php file. So may be the problem in falsh with SSL??